# Yii2 abort request and sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

After page fully loaded, i make ajax request to an action.

While waiting for response from action (it takes 2 or 3 seconds), if user clicks on other link, i want to abort previous request and kill mysql process at once.

How can i do this?

I tried to do like this

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
/*
params
*/
});

//before unload page 
xhr.abort();
```

but i think, that it will not kill sql process.

Answer (score 0):

Make a named ajax. Here is `ajx` is named

```
var formData = {};//Your data for post
var ajx = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",// Http verbs
    url: "filename.php",// file to request
    data: formData,
    success: function(response){
        console.log("ajax completed");
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Stop ajax request by clicking button

```
$( "#button_id" ).click(function() {
    ajx.abort();
});
```

Comment: It stops an ajax request, but mysql query continues to execute. Mysql query not aborting on ajx.abort()

Comment: to stop your mysql process you need to make another ajax to make this command from server side : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9938302/2815635

Comment: Good idea, but i cant send another request, untill the previous one is finished.